# Change Password SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, password

Can I change the SharePoint user password?

By central administration or by code?

I'm using SharePoint 2013 on Windows Server 2008 R2 standard.

Comment: Which authentication scheme are your using in sharepoint?

Comment: Or are you referring to the farm account? your question is unclear.

Comment: form base authentication

Answer (score 1):

if you are talking about the SharePoint Services accounts which use to run services / App Pools etc, I am guessing those IDs are already in the SharePoint Managed account sections.([to understand read this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262502%28v=office.15%29.aspx)).

if you want to change the Managed account password, you have both choices either central admin or Powershell.

You have couple of options in the SharePoint, from central > Security > Configure Managed Account....

- you can automate the process and configure it to change automatically
- You can change the password in the AD then update the password in sharePoint
- you can change the password directly from SharePoint to AD with random password.
  From Powershell you can take the advantage of [Set-SPMangedAccount](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607617%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

  $m = Get-SPManagedAccount –Identity "DOMAINx\UserY"
  Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $m –AutoGeneratePassword true

HelpFul resource:

[Configure automatic password change in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724280%28v=office.15%29.aspx#section1)

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262502(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262502%28v=office.15%29.aspx)